# Can I use pipe as read at parent and write in child?

Tags: c, pipe, parent-child

I'm now learning how to use pipes correctly. I found examples only for write in parent and read in child, but I want to know how can I do it reverse. I tried like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){

  int  p1[2], p2[2];
  char original[]="This is a string\n ";

  pid_t child2;
  pid_t child=fork();

  if (child>0)
  {
    child2 = fork();
    if(child2>0){
      wait();
      printf("I'm the parrent.\n");

      close(p1[1]);
      close(p2[1]);

      printf("Parrent read p1:\n");
      if (read(p1[0], original, sizeof(original)) == -1)
        perror("read() error in parent p1");
      else printf("parent read '%s' from pipe 1\n", original);

      printf("Parrent read p2:\n");
      if (read(p2[0], original, sizeof(original)) == -1)
        perror("read() error in parent p2");
      else printf("parent read '%s' from pipe 2\n", original);
    }
    else{
      printf("Child2 \n");
      pipe(p2);
      close(p2[0]);
      if (write(p2[1], original, sizeof(original)+1) == -1)
        perror("write() error in child2");
      //close(p2[1]);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Child1 \n");

    pipe(p1);
    close(p1[0]);
    if (write(p1[1], original, sizeof(original)+1) == -1)
      perror("write() error in child1");
    //close(p1[1]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But this way give to me error at reading in parent. `read() error in parent p1: Bad file descriptor` both times, at `p1` and also at `p2`. So, can I do this this way or not? Or this is just something trivial error?

Comment: It's perfectly possible to do it; you simply reverse the normal sense.  Find any question with two-way communication between parent and child (that doesn't use sockets) and you'll find examples.  You need to create the pipes before you fork the child that will use it.    You also need to ensure you close enough file descriptors in each child, and in the parent.

Comment: You're getting errors because you're not calling pipe() before forking and your p1 and p2 arrays are being used uninitialized in most places.

Comment: It's not clear that you should wait as early as you do, either.  In general, you should not call `wait()` until you get EOF on a pipe before closing it and then waiting for the dead child (or soon to be dead child).  Your call to `wait()` is erroneous, in part because you omit `#include <sys/wait.h>`.  You are also missing `#include <unistd.h>`, but you don't really need `#include <sys/types.h>`.

Comment: @Shawn you have right. Please write it as an answer an then I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you these are interesting remark. I use wait there because If I don't use it then the `parent` has begun when the `child2` is not started yet. I tried with `#include <sys/wait.h>` but also the same thing happens.

Comment: If you include the header, the compiler should tell you that `wait()` expects an `int *` argument which you are not supplying.  You can provide a null pointer too.  Your call with no arguments is just wrong, and the compiler should complain if you include the `<sys/wait.h>` header (and should complain that the function is undeclared if you don't include it).  If you're not getting complaints, you've either got too old a compiler or you aren't using enough warning options (though warning options should not be necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said you just need to invert the indexes for closing the pipes and the read/write.

Your code was almost correct. Two things were wrong: on the parent you were first closing the pipes and then calling `pipe()`: it should be the other way round: first you create both of the pipes and then close the corresponding element, all in the parent.

Secondly you should call `wait` after setting the pipes otherwise it does not work. Guessing you want to wait for all the children you should call `wait(NULL)`. I do not know what you meant with `wait()`.

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){

  int  p1[2], p2[2];
  char original[]="This is a string\n ";

  pid_t child2;
  pid_t child=fork();

  if (child>0)
  {
    child2 = fork();
    if(child2>0){

      printf("I'm the parrent.\n");
      pipe(p1); //ADDED
      pipe(p2); //ADDED
      close(p1[1]);
      close(p2[1]);
      wait(NULL); //DON'T GET IT WHY? if u want to wait all children,
      //wait after setting the pipes.
      printf("Parrent read p1:\n");
      if (read(p1[0], original, sizeof(original)) == -1)
        perror("read() error in parent p1");
      else printf("parent read '%s' from pipe 1\n", original);

      printf("Parrent read p2:\n");
      if (read(p2[0], original, sizeof(original)) == -1)
        perror("read() error in parent p2");
      else printf("parent read '%s' from pipe 2\n", original);
    }
    else{
      printf("Child2 \n");
      //pipe(p2); ERROR HERE
      close(p2[0]);
      if (write(p2[1], original, sizeof(original)+1) == -1)
        perror("write() error in child2");
      //close(p2[1]);
    }
  }
}
```